# how set image set full width and set UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit?

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to set a image for UITableviewcell but imageview contentmode is **UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit** and also set full width depends on width height of **UIIMageView** is change,how to do that.

Comment: You want to modify the contentmode of the cell.imageView ? or you want to add your own imageview?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `UIIMageView` content mode to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` or `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`

**Edited**

Use following `UITableView's` Method

Add you `UIImageView` Height in `NSMutableArray` **(heightsArray)**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return  [heightsArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i need to set cell height,because it over a next cell text

Comment: @sabeer- i can't get it ..plz add image

Comment: @sabeer- you want to ser heigh of UITableViewCell ??